# How to import FBX with multitrack (multi take) animations?

Tags: animation, import, file-format

I have a .fbx file with many multitrack animations, and after importing it into Blender, only the first one shows up in timeline. When i import it to Unity, all the animations are there, so the file is OK. Is it possible to get these animations to Blender somehow? Maybe there is some software to convert this fbx into single track, and then import to Blender?